# How to Format/Mask DGV

Tags: .net, vb.net, ms-access, datagridview

On my previous app, DGV works well, displaying what the access data has. But now, it doesn't, why?
**DGV**
[image]
**Database** (*those 3 fields have a format of 00,00,0000 respectively*)
[image]

Comment: What is the column datatype?

Comment: number with format 00,00,0000 on database. I was just confuse why is it not working on my new app. But I only copied the controls from the last. The only difference is that there now a format on access.

Comment: Did you have a `DataRowBound` event where you reinforced the format?

Comment: Try something like this: `dgv.Columns(0).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "##"`

Comment: that didn't work. Where is that `DataRowBound`?

Comment: You don't have to set it in code, do it in the editor.

Comment: Also try: N2 instead of the D's

Comment: If that doesn't work make sure your column is numerical, by default it's a string, if that's the case no formatting will work. Another specifier that can be used is n0 as well

Comment: N2 is for decimal points, I've tried it, :) it would be `1.00`

Comment: Ok when you used N2 did it work? Or no?

Comment: Check my answer at the bottom. That's what I did.

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if there will be a better option:

```
dgvFarrowing.Columns("Week").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "D2"
dgvFarrowing.Columns("SowOrder").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "D2"
dgvFarrowing.Columns("Piglet").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "D4"
```